# i don't know how solvw it

Tags: python, mysql

error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

```
upi = upi_entry.get()
mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="deol9646",
    database="train_login",
)
mycursor = mysqldb.cursor()

try:
    mycursor.execute(
        """create table if not exists upi_data(upi text)"""
    )
    sql = "INSERT INTO UPI_DATA (UPI) VALUES (%s)"
    val = upi
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mysqldb.commit()
    lastid = mycursor.lastrowid
    messagebox.showinfo("information", "upi inserted successfully...")
    upi_entry.delete(0, END)
    upi_entry.focus_set()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    mysqldb.rollback()
    mysqldb.close()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters need to be a tuple; you're passing in `val` as a single value, so the MySQL driver doesn't turn `%s` into anything and that ends up a syntax error.

Add a comma to make a parenthesized expression (`(upi)`) into a 1-tuple: `(upi,)`

```
sql = "INSERT INTO UPI_DATA (UPI) VALUES (%s)"
val = (upi,)
```